# Lower central series of Free group 4

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I have a question. I found the following statement in some paper.

Let $F$ be free group on two generator $x$ and $y$ and  $F_i$ be $i$-th component of lower central series of $F$. If $F$ is generated mod $F_1=[F,F]$ by $b_1,...,b_n$  then $F_r$ is generated mod $F_{r+1}$ by elements of the form
$[b_i,w]$ with $w \in F_{r-1}$. So  for an element $c$ in $F_r$, Using standard commutator identities, we can express $c$ in the form
$$c=[b_1,w_1]...[b_n,w_n] d$$
where $d\in F_{r+1}$ and $w_i\in F_{r-1}$.
 I need to find algorithmically elements $w_1,...,w_n\in F_{r-1}$ and $d\in F_{r+1}$. For example in the free group $F<{x,y}>$, let $b_1=x^{-2}y^{-3}$, $b_2=x^{-2}(xy)^5$. I know that $c=b_2^{-1}b_1^{-1}xy^2\in F_1=[F,F]$. How could I express $c=[b_1,w_1][b_1,w_2]d$ where $w_1,w_2\in F$ and $d\in F_2$?

Comment: I explained how to express $c$ as a product of commutators in your previous post. You can then use the commutator laws to complete the process. For example (with the convenetion $[g,h] = g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$), we have $[gh,w] = [g,w]^h[h,w] = [h,[g,w]][g,w][h,w]$.

Comment: OK I see, thanks a lot

Comment: Dear Holk by this way I could express $c$ as a product of commutators on x and y. But I want express $c$ as product of $[b_i,w_i]$ and $d$.

Comment: To do that you will need to write $x$ and $y$ as words in the $b_i$ modulo $[F,F]$, which must be possible since you are assuming that the $b_i$ generate $F$ modulo $[F,F]$. It will get harder if you want to do the same thing lower down the central series.